# What may be wrong with my hidden form fields for Paypal custom cart

Tags: paypal

I have two Carts on a site I am working on.  One works just fine.  The other though is not, and I can't find the problem at all.

The code for the form is blow (hidden domain name and email of course):

```
<form id="paypalpayment" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="order_id" value="24" />
                <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
                <input type="hidden" name="business" value="pay@xxxxxxxx.com" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Shopping Cart" />
                <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="Order-24" />
                <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="23.49" />
                <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="My" />
                <input type="hidden" name="last_name" value="Surname" />
                <input type="hidden" name="address1" value="My Street">
                <input type="hidden" name="address2" value="My Village">
                <input type="hidden" name="city" value="My City">
                <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="My Post Code">
                <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" />
                <input type="hidden" name="tax_rate" value="20.00" />
                <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
                <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.xxxxxxxx.co.uk/shop/payments/itempaymentreceived/24" />
                <input type="hidden" name="cancel_url" value="http://www.xxxxxxxx.co.uk/shop/payments/paymentcancelled" />
                <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.xxxxxxxx.co.uk/shop/payments/itemipn/24" />
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-wide btn-primary" value="Pay Now" id="btnSubmit" name="btnSubmit"/>
                </div>
            </form>
```

I know it a case of not seeing the wood for the trees, but any pointer would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly is it about the cart that isn't working?

Comment: Not sure, Paypal's error messages come in one size - useless.

Still, I managed to fix the problem by turning off auto return in my Paypal settings.  Fortunately my boss prefers not have auto return.